# Plugin with id 'sonar' not found?

Tags: java, gradle

When trying to build my java project using Gradle I get the following issue:

```
plugin with id 'sonar' not found
```

at the following line in my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'sonar'
```

This was previously working with Gradle version `1.7` and `Java 7`, however I have now updated to these newer versions:

```
gradle : 3.4.1
Java: 1.8
```

What could be causing this and how could I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sonar plugin was renamed to 'org.sonarqube'.

To use this plugin you need to add a dependency:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.2.1"
  }
}
```

And then you can apply the plugin:

```
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
```

Also see the [plugin page](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube).